# How to handle command line arguments in a gtk application?

Tags: rust, gtk, gtk3

How do I handle command line arguments like `--config <file>` in a rust based gtk application?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a call to gtk::Application::add_main_option as documented here - https://gtk-rs.org/docs/gio/trait.ApplicationExt.html#tymethod.add_main_option.

```
gtk_app.add_main_option(
  "config",
  glib::Char::new("c"),
  glib::OptionFlags::IN_MAIN,
  glib::OptionArg::Filename,
  "some description",
  Some("some other description")
);
```

then add a call to

```
gtk_app.connect_handle_local_options( ... );
```